# Como criar novas rotas de forma dinâmica python/flask

Tags: python, flask

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que faz predições a partir de modelos, e queria implementar uma funcionalidade que me permita criar novas rotas através de uma função.

```
config = json.loads(open('config.json').read())

def create_models(config):
    for key, val in config.items():
        globals()[key] = initialize_model(val)

@app.route('/predict1', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predict1():
        if request.method == 'POST':
                try:
                        information= request.data
                except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
                        return abort(400, e)

                try:
                        results_inventory = predict1.pred(information)
                        inventory = set_inventory(results_inventory)
                        return jsonify(inventory)
                except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
                        return abort(500, e)
```

Tudo está funcionando conforme desejado, `config` carrega meu JSON com as informações necessárias, `create_models` carrega meus modelos, `predict1` recebe as informações e devolve os resultados da análise.

Acontece que tenho mais de um modelo e queria disponibilizar uma nova rota para cada um deles, aqui um exemplo do meu `config.json`:

```js
{
    "predict1":
    {
        "model": "cfg/configurationfile1.txt",
        "load": 115,
        "threshold": 0.25,
    },

    "predict2":
    {
        "model": "cfg/configurationfile2.txt",
        "load": 600,
        "threshold": 0.10,

    }

}
```

Como tenho dois modelos dentro do meu `config.json`, precisei criar uma nova rota manualmente, que é idêntica a primeira alterando apenas os locais do código onde aparecem `predict1` para `predict2`. Ficou assim:

```
@app.route('/predict1', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def predict1():
            if request.method == 'POST':
                    try:
                            information= request.data
                    except Exception as e:
                            print(e)
                            return abort(400, e)

                    try:
                            results_inventory = predict1.pred(information)
                            inventory = set_inventory(results_inventory)
                            return jsonify(inventory)
                    except Exception as e:
                            print(e)
                            return abort(500, e)

@app.route('/predict2', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def predict2():
            if request.method == 'POST':
                    try:
                            information= request.data
                    except Exception as e:
                            print(e)
                            return abort(400, e)

                    try:
                            results_inventory = predict2.pred(information)
                            inventory = set_inventory(results_inventory)
                            return jsonify(inventory)
                    except Exception as e:
                            print(e)
                            return abort(500, e)
```

Existe uma maneira de automatizar esse processo de criação de rotas, para que o próprio script gere uma nova rota sempre que uma nova configuração aparecer no meu JSON?

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito o seu problema. Você quer ler o arquivo JSON no começo e daí criar as rotas? Ou depois de criadas as rotas, dependendo do que os usuários chamarem, criar novas rotas com base no que for houver no arquivo JSON?

Comment: Olá Victor, eu desejo criar rotas a partir do conteúdo do meu JSON.

Comment: Então, a resposta abaixo deve ser o que você quer ou algo muito próximo a isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro que o `if request.method == 'POST':` é desnecessário, bastaria retirar o `GET` do decorator acima e o daí não precisa mais do `if`.

Acho que dá para fazer assim:

```
def pega_dados():
    import json
    with open('config.json') as f:
        return json.load(f)

@app.route('/<key>', methods = ['POST'])
def predict(key):
    config = pega_dados()
    try:
        model = config[key]['model']
        load = config[key]['load']
        threshold = config[key]['threshold']
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return abort(404, e)

    try:
        information = request.data
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return abort(400, e)

    try:
        results_inventory = predict.pred(information)
        inventory = set_inventory(results_inventory)
        return jsonify(inventory)
   except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return abort(500, e)
```

No entanto, não acho que esse `predict.pred` vai fazer o que você quer, da mesma forma que o `predict1.pred` e o `predict2.pred` do seu código original. Acho que isso daí era para ser algo diferente. De qualquer forma, nesse ponto você já deve ter o `model`, o `load` e o `threshold`.

Se o `key` da requisição não estiver dentro do arquivo de configurações, o resultado será um 404.

Note também que se por algum motivo, o seu JSON for alterado em tempo de execução, as rotas irão responder a isso automaticamente. Se você preferir que elas sejam carregadas apenas uma vez no início, evitando ter que reler elas a cada requisição, pode colocar o `config = pega_dados()` para fora da função.

Comment: Você está certo Victor o predict1.pred está escrito errado, no meu código já foi alterado para globals()['predict1' + 'model']. A função pega_dados() que você definiu tem alguma vantagem em relação a config = json.loads(open('config.json').read()) pois acho a segunda sintaxe mais elegante. Muito obrigado resolveu todo o problema com <key>, eu não conhecia essa sintaxe.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves É que usando `config = json.loads(open('config.json').read())`, o arquivo aberto não será fechado. Ele só é fechado com uma chamada explícita a `close()` ou implicitamente usando o bloco `with`.